# How to change transition values according to orientation in a MotionLayout?

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I create a scene that resizes a view from full to half the screen. It works on portrait mode, but the layout_height value is not enough for landscape mode. Is there a way to set a different value of a property in a XML scene file according to a specific orientation? If not, do I have to change it programmatically and how?

```
<MotionScene 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<Transition
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
    motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
    motion:duration="500">
   <KeyFrameSet>
   </KeyFrameSet>
</Transition>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
    <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/content_parent"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</ConstraintSet>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/content_parent"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/section_height"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</ConstraintSet>
```

UPDATE @ivan-wooll
Here's how I did:

```
//dimens.xml
<dimen name="section_height" tools:ignore="ResourceCycle">@dimen/section_height</dimen>

//dimens.xml(port)
<dimen name="section_height">280dp</dimen>

//dimens.xml(land)
<dimen name="section_height">60dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved my problem with XML (@ivan-wooll suggestion, thumbs up) and Kotlin code (mine)

```
override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
    val csEnd = binding.motionLayoutVideo.getConstraintSet(R.id.end)
    var consHeight= resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.section_height)
    csEnd.apply {
       constrainHeight(R.id.content_parent, consHeight)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract your height values to a dimension resource.
Create `res/values-port` and `res/values-land` directories and add a `dimens.xml` file in each of these directories that contains the dimension resource for each orientation.

Comment: A values folder already exists, with a base dimens.xml, so I created 2 versions of that file for port and land, and referenced them with the same name (on base I added tools:ignore="ResourceCycle"). The result is the same: it uses only the value of the orientation detected during activity loading.

Comment: In which dimens files do you have references to the dimension you use to define the height value?

Comment: You should be able to remove it from the main dimens/xml file instead of ignoring it

Comment: You have this line in your start constraint  android:layout_height="match_parent"??

Comment: That doesn't help. Now I'm trying to change it programmatically, but I see there's no layoutParams on a constraintSet.